# Using images for radio input buttons without styling label

Tags: javascript, css, input, radio-button

I'm using an app on my Shopify store which provides product options on an ecommerce site. Annoyingly, I can't work out how I can change the radio buttons for the options so that an image is used for the selection. I've been trying to get this to work for hours but without success.

The problem is that the app outputs the radio inputs in a way that I can't seem to target the label. I've read many workarounds that use the label technique and hiding the input. However, my output looks like this:

```html
<div class="shappify_option_value">
  <label class="shappify_radio_option">
    <input id="255415_0" class="bold_option_child shappify_option_255415 " type="radio" value="None" data-conditional-value="None" name="properties[Wax finish]" data-product-handle="" data-option-key="rb_255415_0">
    None
  </label>
  <label class="shappify_radio_option">
    <input id="255415_1" class="bold_option_child shappify_option_255415 price-change " type="radio" value="Light/clear" data-conditional-value="Light%2Fclear" name="properties[Wax finish]" data-price="8.00" data-variant="25548381447" data-product-handle="wax-finish" data-option-key="rb_255415_1">
    Light/clear
  </label>
  <label class="shappify_radio_option">
    <input id="255415_2" class="bold_option_child shappify_option_255415 price-change " type="radio" value="Light brown" data-conditional-value="Light%20brown" name="properties[Wax finish]" data-price="8.00" data-variant="25548382215" data-product-handle="wax-finish" data-option-key="rb_255415_2">
    Light brown
  </label>
</div>
```

Is there a way that I can work around this? Ideally I just want to use an image to select between the options without any text.

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Why don't you use <input type="image"> instead of radio buttons ?

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned...I can't access any of this output as it's sent from an app out of my control. I can only think to try and somehow use CSS or Javascript/Jquery to get around it.